# Invalid column name - one-to-many relation - Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity with two foreign keys only on one of them I get an exception:

> Invalid column name LookUpTypId

Both have the same code, but only one of them cause exception

```
public class Term
{
    public Term ()
    {
        RequestTimes = new HashSet<RequestTime>();
    }

    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    public string AcademicYear { get; set; }
    public string Semester { get; set; }
    public int? NumberOfDays { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool Reserve { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RequestTime> RequestTimes { get; set; }
}

public class LookUp
{
    public LookUp()
    {
        RequestTimes = new HashSet<RequestTime>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RequestTime> RequestTimes { get; set; }
}

public class RequestTime
{
    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToTime { get; set; }
    public int RequestMaxNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual int LookUpTypId { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal TermId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TermId")]
    public virtual Term Term { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LookUpTypId")]
    public virtual LookUp LookUp { get; set; }
}


//relationship  in RequestTimeMap
this.HasRequired<LookUp>(rt => rt.LookUp)
            .WithMany(lk => lk.RequestTimes)
            .HasForeignKey(rt => rt.LookUpTypId);

this.HasRequired<Term>(rt => rt.Term)
            .WithMany(t => t.RequestTimes)
            .HasForeignKey(rt => rt.TermId);
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you 100% sure the database column has the same name?

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes, the column name is exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the ForeignKey attribute should be used in the property that represents your foreign key.

If you have a object as a property, it should be right above it... unless you also have a separate property for it's Id. In that case, you should use the attribute above the Id property.

```
[ForeignKey("LookUpTypId")]
public virtual int LookUpTypId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("TermId")]
public virtual decimal TermId { get; set; }


public virtual Term Term { get; set; }

public virtual LookUp LookUp { get; set; }
```

And... is this ID decimal?

Comment: thank you for your reply and yes this is decimal. My problem solved. As "alexander" said, my property was not exactly like the column name and it caused the exception